Did Descartes declare the "Non Cogito" first, prior to "cogito ergo sum"
I took A-Level Philosophy, during which we studied Descartes "Meditations" at length.
I remember our teacher explaining that, whilst "Cogito ergo sum" was the famous phrasing, Descartes original formulation of the concept was the "Non cogito" - presented in the opposite construction:

It would be absurd to claim "I do not think"! For if I make that claim ... what is it that is thinking that claim. This is absurd and therefore I must conclude that I both exist and think.

And that "Cogito ergo sum", came from a later writing (a letter to a friend summarising his position, I think?)
Briefly googling, however, hasn't shown me any reference to a "Non Cogito", or to an argument of this structure.
Is my recollection (and/or my teacher) wrong?

The 'original' cogito is in the Second Meditation, see SEP:"I have convinced myself that there is absolutely nothing in the world, no sky, no earth, no minds, no bodies. Does it now follow that I too do not exist? No: if I convinced myself of something then I certainly existed. But there is a deceiver of supreme power and cunning who is deliberately and constantly deceiving me. In that case I too undoubtedly exist, if he is deceiving me." The quip "I think, therefore I am" is from the Second Reply (to Mersenne).
